# Submit an HTML for via jquery submit() method

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

First of all ..sorry for an easy one I tried but really cant fix it on my own.

I am trying to validate the `typeof` input, but it is throwing `undefined` & `not a number`.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong(I will be really thankful to you, if you explain it in brief instead of just pasting the solution as I am learning jQuery this time.)

As a note - `jquery` is included and working(tested that part).

WHOLE CODE-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Radom Guess Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").submit(function(){
            var num = $("number").val();
            console.log(num);
            if(typeof num === 'number' )
                console.log("its a number "+ num);
            else
                console.log("its not a number");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
    <h1>Game Of Random Guess</h1>
    <h3>Enter any number between 1 to 100</h3>
</div>
    <form id="myform" name="myform" method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Code is still reflecting "not a number" however i entered 45.

Comment: you need the #: `var num = $("#number").val();`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var num = $("number").val();
```

should be

```
var num = $("#number").val();
```

and if for some reason you need to make sure it is evaluated as a number, you can do this:

```
num = parseInt(num);
```

Comment: Is HASH really require..in JS document by id works without hashes ..so in jQuery is it necessary to add ?

Comment: @Trialcoder jQuery selector context is based around css selectors.  Any dom element can be accessed the same way you would write a css rule for it.

Comment: Is ir still throwing `its not a number` error although i entered 45

Comment: jQuery uses a selector engine which works using css selectors to retrieve document nodes. Its not the same as getElementByID, and is in fact much more powerful

Comment: @Trialcoder Yes it is required since you could be selecting a number of different things not just an element by id. If this is surprising I would suggest that you need to go over a jquery tutorial. http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: @Trialcoder it may be evaluating your number as a string.  You can wrap the whole thing in a parseInt() to make sure you get a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in

```
var num = $("number").val();
```

You must type

```
var num = $("#number").val();
```